# Given this (see inside) situation, is it worth it to use Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, batch-processing

We are about to create a Java standard project which is actually a batch process that executes at console.

Every "batch" uses only `select` statements on multiple tables from different DBs. But we'll be doing around thousands of `select`s.

I'm not really familiar with the "whole" of Hibernate but is it worth using it in this situation?

Comment: if you 're dealing with objects and their storage and retrieval from DB , hibernate totally is worthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessary. As your description, your db operation is quite simple, so why not just use jdbc directly or some simple libs such as spring jdbc template (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)

There's no need to import a huge dependency like Hibernate in my opinion. The time of learning and configuring Hibernate is uncertain, so why not just focus on the main project requirements and make it simple at the first beginning.

Comment: Okay but with that reasoning, you'd -never- learn anything new. I do agree that Hibernate (or an ORM tool in general) is overkill for this project though, it only becomes a benefit when you have a complex data model hierarchy on which you will do a wide variety of operations.

Comment: @Gimby Choose the right tool is more important in this case. Learning new stuffs is always interesting but whether to adopt in real world project is different. There's always some other ways to learn if you do have interest.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at [Spring Batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/):

> Spring Batch is a lightweight, comprehensive batch framework designed
>   to enable the development of robust batch applications vital for the
>   daily operations of enterprise systems. Spring Batch builds upon the
>   productivity, POJO-based development approach, and general ease of use
>   capabilities people have come to know from the Spring Framework, while
>   making it easy for developers to access and leverage more advanced
>   enterprise services when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you will perform `select` on many different tables and/or need to manipulate the data, so the easiest way is retrieve rows from database as instances of objects i strongly recommend `hibernate`.